# Determine space occupied by the text in a given width in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an android application. I have a xml layout. On top of my xml layout I have an image view,textview, and finally another textview in a horizontal row. Texts in the textview keeps changing depending on the user selection.

I want to determine if the text in the centre textview would fit without overlapping with the adjacent textview. If it overlaps, I want to bring down the entire text in the central textview below the first Imageview.

Is there a simple way to determine if the text would fit in the given space without overlapping with the adjacent textview?

[image]

Comment: can you post screenshot of your current UI?

Comment: please post code here ......

Comment: @rajanks The layout is not ready but I have posted an image to give you an idea of what I am looking for. I want the second textview to go below the image view if the text overlaps with the adjacent textview. Please help!

Comment: Its a bit unclear about what you exactly want.Attaching the ss of current UI which you have managed to code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `heights` and rearrange your center `textview` below `imageview` if it overlaps with right `textview`

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
//set text in center and right text view
int centerTextViewHeight = centerTextView.getPaint().getTextBounds(centerTextView.getText(), 0, centerTextView.getText().length(), bounds).height();

int rightTextViewHeight = rightTextView.getPaint().getTextBounds(rightTextView.getText(), 0, rightTextView.getText().length(), bounds).height();

if(centerTextViewHeight > rightTextViewHeight ){
  // move center textview below image view based on your implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Should I be comparing the width or the height?